# Excel find corresponding value, return `0` if not found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(C2,'Jul-14'!A:A,'Jul-14'!B:B)
```

Where:

- `C2` = "Aruba (AW)"

The sheet "Jul-14" doesn't contain the value "Aruba (AW)" in column `A`.  When this happens, it seems to take the closet match and return the value in column `B`.  I need it to return `0` if no exact match is found, or the `B` column value if an exact match is found.

I've tried changing the function to `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP` but it doesn't ever return any value.

Comment: @shauno-88 provides a good answer but I'm interested in why OP used the LOOKUP function which, according to help is only provided for backward compatability?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should lookup the value in C2 against the values on the sheet in column A, if it finds a match then it will show it, if it doesn't then it will throw an error which will then return 0

```
=iferror(vlookup(C2,'Jul-14'!A:B,2,False),0)
```